# Mongoid paperclip ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, paperclip

I have a view where I can create, edit an Room and I can chose a photo for that room when I chose the photo and click the update button I get an error that says:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/images/localhost/photos/images/56f9/2fae/23fb/c028/d600/0003/original/large3.jpg"):
```

Here class model :

```
class Room
  include Mongoid::Document
  validates :listing_name, length: {maximum: 50}, presence: true
  field :home_type, type: String
  field :room_type, type: String
  embeds_many :photos
  belongs_to :user
end

class Photo
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Paperclip
  embedded_in :room, :inverse_of => :photos
  has_mongoid_attached_file :image,

    :styles => {
      :original => ['1920x1680>', :jpg],
      :small    => ['100x100#',   :jpg],
      :medium   => ['250x250',    :jpg],
      :large    => ['500x500>',   :jpg]
    },
    :convert_options => { :all => '-background white -flatten +matte' }

   validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end

class RoomsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @room = current_user.rooms.build(room_params)
    if @room.save
      if params[:images]
        params[:images].each do |image|
          @room.photos.create(image: image)
        end
      end

      @photos = @room.photos
      redirect_to edit_room_path (@room), notice: "Saved..."
    else
      render :new
    end
      end
end
```

Here Route

```
  resources :rooms
  resources :posts
  resources :comments
  resources :photos

  resources :rooms do
    resources :reservations, only: [:create]
  end

  get '/preload' => 'reservations#preload'
```

here views

```
<% if @photos %>
    <div class="row">
      <% @photos.each do |photo|  %>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading preview">
              <%= image_tag photo.image.url() %>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
              <span class="pull-right">
                <%= link_to photo, remote: true, method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure?"} do %>
                    <i class="fa fa-times fa-lg"></i>
                <% end %>
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Anybody help me please, whats' wrong my source code :-( ...??

Comment: Hm, a bit of your logfile could help. Als the view that is using those photos.

Comment: i have error like this ; Started GET "/images/localhost//photos/images/56fc/3536/23fb/c01f/5700/0002/original/te.jpg?1459369269" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-03-31 03:21:11 +0700

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/images/localhost/photos/images/56fc/3536/23fb/c01f/5700/0002/original/te.jpg"):
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'

Comment: Something's wrong in your view, could you post that as well?

Comment: here is short code views <%= image_tag photo.image.url() %> Image not display